# Plot using pgfplots from a text file in long form (vs wide form)?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, plot

In the statistical programming language [`R`](http://www.r-project.org/), there are two different forms to represent data.
The *wide form* looks like the following:

```
     subject time age weight height
1 John Smith    1  33     90   1.87
2 Mary Smith    1  NA     55   1.54
```

The *long form* looks like the following:

```
     subject variable value
1 John Smith     time  1.00
2 Mary Smith     time  1.00
3 John Smith      age 33.00
4 Mary Smith      age    NA
5 John Smith   weight 90.00
6 Mary Smith   weight 55.00
7 John Smith   height  1.87
8 Mary Smith   height  1.54
```

Source of example: Hadley Wickham's [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12).
But note that I changed Mary's weight to 55 where previous it was NA.

Is it possible to read in a text file which is in long form, and to plot for example the height against the weight?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  % the following code doesn't work, but communicates the idea
  % of what I want to work
  \addplot [x variable=height,y variable=weight] {input.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The reason why I am asking this question is because I want to plot the output of a computer simulation program which I have written, and it is easier to output in long form than it is in wide form.
Currently, I use an `R` script `convert.R` to read in the text file `in.txt` in long form and to convert it into a text file `out.txt` in wide form, which [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) can read.
It would be more convenient if somehow pgfplots could read and process `in.txt` directly without requiring me to run `convert.R` manually.

Comment: `pgfplotstable` comes without support for the "long form". If you want some conversion script which is independent of R, you can consider writing a TeX script (based on `pgfplotstable` and basic TeX programming) or perhaps a LUA script. Or you invoke your `R` script via shell escape or via `\addplot shell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[converted from my comment]:

`pgfplotstable` comes without support for the "long form". If you want some conversion script which is independent of R, you can consider writing a TeX script (based on `pgfplotstable` and basic TeX programming) or perhaps a LUA script. Or you invoke your `R` script via shell escape or via `\addplot shell`